# How to configure HornetQ client with standalone server cluster (configured using JGroups TCP)

Tags: hornetq, jgroups

I have configured 2 hornetq standalone servers in clustered mode using groups (tcp) as i cant use default UDP. Below is the configuration.

**hornetq-configuration.xml:**

```
<broadcast-groups>
    <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <jgroups-file>jgroups-tcp.xml</jgroups-file>
        <jgroups-channel>hornetq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
        <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
    </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
    <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <jgroups-file>jgroups-tcp.xml</jgroups-file>
        <jgroups-channel>hornetq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
    </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
```

**Jgroups.xml:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
<TCP bind_port="7800"
     recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:5M}"
     send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:5M}"
     max_bundle_size="64K"
     max_bundle_timeout="30"
     use_send_queues="true"
     sock_conn_timeout="300"

     timer_type="new3"
     timer.min_threads="4"
     timer.max_threads="10"
     timer.keep_alive_time="3000"
     timer.queue_max_size="500"

     thread_pool.enabled="true"
     thread_pool.min_threads="2"
     thread_pool.max_threads="8"
     thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
     thread_pool.queue_enabled="true"
     thread_pool.queue_max_size="10000"
     thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"

     oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
     oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1"
     oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8"
     oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
     oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
     oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
     oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"/>

<TCPPING
         initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:hornetq-server1-ip[7800], hornetq-server1-ip[7900], hornetq-server2-ip[7800], hornetq-server2-ip[7900]}"
         port_range="1"/>
<MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
         max_interval="30000"/>
<FD_SOCK/>
<FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
<BARRIER />
<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
               discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
<UNICAST3 />
<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
               max_bytes="4M"/>
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
            view_bundling="true"/>
<MFC max_credits="2M"
     min_threshold="0.4"/>
<FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
<!--RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/-->
<pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
```

Servers work fine i.e., if the live goes down, backup takes its place.

**Client producer:**

```
TransportConfiguration[] servers = new TransportConfiguration[2];
List<Configuration> configurations = ... // user defined class
for (int i = 0; i < configurations.size(); i++) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("host", configurations.get(i).getHost());
    map.put("port", configurations.get(i).getPort());
    servers[i] = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), map);
}
ServerLocator locator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithHA(servers);
locator.setReconnectAttempts(5);

factory = locator.createSessionFactory();
session = factory.createSession();
producer = session.createProducer(queueName);
```

**Client Consumer:**

```
ClientSessionFactory factory = locator.createSessionFactory();
for (int i = 1; i <= nReceivers; i++) {
    ClientSession session = factory.createSession(true, true, 1);
    sessions.add(session);
    if (i == 1) {
        Thread.sleep(10000); // waiting to download cluster information
    }
    session.start();
    ClientConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queueName);
    consumer.setMessageHandler(handler);
}
```

**Issue:**

1. Client (producer) doesnt automatically fall back if the server connected to, goes down,  while sending messages.
2. The sessions created using same client factory is always connecting to one server (as opposed to documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.beta1/docs/user-manual/html/clusters.html#clusters.client.loadbalancing)

So it seems the client never gets the cluster information. I also dont find any documentation for configuring a client to use jgroups (needed?) to connect to a hornetq cluster.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that i can use jgroups on client side too.
Detailed solution can be found [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/253574)